# Most efficient way in Java to scrub a string "$xx.xx/mo" and return in format of "xx.xx"

Tags: java, string

I am scraping strings from a web page in the format of $xx.xx/mo (e.g. $54.89/mo ) and would like to extract just the numbers in the format of xx.xx (e.g. 54.89 ) also as a string.

Currently I've written the following method that works fine:

```
public static String extractPriceString(String Price){
    if (Price == null)
        return null;

    return Price.split("/")[0].substring(1).replace(" ", "");
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Would

```
.replaceAll("$","").replaceAll("/mo","").replace(" ", "")
```

be better?

Comment: Efficient in terms of? What issue did you see with your approach?

Comment: I'll use regular expression for this thing.

Comment: @pepuch Since OP used the term "Efficient", regex wouldn't go well with that. Remove the *efficient* from there, and yes *Regex* is the way to go.

Comment: Will your string be always in that format?

Comment: if your number will always be of the format `xx.xx` then you could just do `price.substring(1, 6)`.

Comment: I'm a java newbie and am just wondering about the correct way of doing things. I will be using this method repeatedly to scrub thousands of prices. The prices range of $0.01/mo - $999.99/mo    Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d.]+[\\d]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("$54.88/mo");
```

Tested on [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: This doesn't work as is in Java. Unfortunately, just because it works in the Ruby tester, doesn't mean it will translate directly to Java.